# Apache-Camel multiple pollenrich() and error on move param

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using apache camel version 2.21.1 and i have a trouble with the pollEnrich 
to download a specific file from ftp.  It looks like when i download 2 file with pollenrich and the operation take some minutes (4 minutes) camel goes in error when moving the first file in the .done directory.
I have this exception:

```
`WARN  o.a.camel.component.file.GenericFileOnCompletion - Error during commit. Exchange[ID-XXX16563-1529920620474-0-8]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - File operation failed: 250 CWD command successful.
 Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error. Code: 250]
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: File operation failed: 250 CWD command successful.
 Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error. Code: 250
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.buildDirectory(FtpOperations.java:352)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileProcessStrategySupport.renameFile(GenericFileProcessStrategySupport.java:106)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy.commit(GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy.java:111)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOnCompletion.processStrategyCommit(GenericFileOnCompletion.java:127)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOnCompletion.onCompletion(GenericFileOnCompletion.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOnCompletion.onComplete(GenericFileOnCompletion.java:57)
    at org.apache.camel.util.UnitOfWorkHelper.doneSynchronizations(UnitOfWorkHelper.java:104)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultUnitOfWork.done(DefaultUnitOfWork.java:243)
    at org.apache.camel.util.UnitOfWorkHelper.doneUow(UnitOfWorkHelper.java:65)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$UnitOfWorkProcessorAdvice.after(CamelInternalProcessor.java:685)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$UnitOfWorkProcessorAdvice.after(CamelInternalProcessor.java:634)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$InternalCallback.done(CamelInternalProcessor.java:251)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:127)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.aws.sqs.SqsConsumer.processBatch(SqsConsumer.java:206)
    at org.apache.camel.component.aws.sqs.SqsConsumer.poll(SqsConsumer.java:111)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1541)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1553)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:71)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__send(FTP.java:545)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:519)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient.sendCommand(FTPSClient.java:568)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:648)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:622)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.pwd(FTP.java:1495)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.printWorkingDirectory(FTPClient.java:2738)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.buildDirectory(FtpOperations.java:329)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1906)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1870)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1815)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:128)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__send(FTP.java:545)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:519)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient.sendCommand(FTPSClient.java:568)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:648)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:622)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.pwd(FTP.java:1495)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.printWorkingDirectory(FTPClient.java:2738)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.getCurrentDirectory(FtpOperations.java:821)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.deleteFile(FtpOperations.java:286)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileProcessStrategySupport.renameFile(GenericFileProcessStrategySupport.java:100)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:431)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:417)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:876)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:847)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    ... 39 common frames omitted`.
```

This is my route:

```
         from(queueSource)
            .errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("direct:dead")
               .useOriginalMessage()
               .maximumRedeliveries(3)
               .redeliveryDelay(180000)
               .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
            )
            .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson,MyClass.class)
            .process(setHeaderWithMyVariableProcessorClass)
            .choice()
                .when(header("DownloadFilename").isEqualTo(true))
                  .pollEnrich()
                   .simple("{{ftp.path}}
                    &useList=false
                    &consumer.bridgeErrorHandler=true
                    &autoCreate=false
                    &username={{ftp.username}}&password={{ftp.password}}             
                    &passiveMode=true
                    &localWorkDirectory={{ftp.localWorkDirectory}}
                    &maxMessagesPerPoll=1
                    &disconnectOnBatchComplete=true
                    &move={{ftp.fullFileDir}}/.done
                    &soTimeout=600000
                    &fileName=${body.getFileAssetName()}")                          
                .aggregationStrategy(new ApplyOldExchangeAggregationStrategy())
                .end()
               .end()
              .choice()
                .when(header("DownloadAttach0").isEqualTo(true))
                  .pollEnrich()
                   .simple("{{ftp.attachmentspath}}&.....&soTimeout=600000&fileName=${body.getAttachmentList()[0]}")
                   .aggregationStrategy(new ApplyOldExchangeAggregationStrategy())
                   .end()
                  .end()                                    
                 .log("<<<<<< ${body} >>>>>>>")                 
                .end();
```

Comment: You can try to disable reusing of previous consumer with `.pollEnrich().simple("ftp://...").cacheSize(-1)`

Comment: @Bedla thanks for suggestion but i have another error with cache size: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: File operation failed: null Connection is not open. Code: 221, it seems that there is something that doesn,t work when the application wait some minutes for commit the exchange and move the first file in the .done directory. I'll try to change the description of my error because i have found that the problem in not the soTimeout